# iOS Testflight "There was an error loading your builds."

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Over the last few days I've tried to set up test flight for my iOS application through iTunes connect, however, whenever, I try to switch on TestFlight, I get an error saying "There was an error loading your builds." and I'm not quite sure what to do, does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you uploading your build? Via Application Loader or Xcode Organizer(after creating an archive of your build)?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue myself

Comment: I'm getting the same error at the moment. I've logged a support ticket so I'll update if I hear anything back

Comment: I'm experiencing the issue as well.

Comment: yeah, same issue here.  I tried the suggestion from DrMembrane below but no luck.

Answer (score 26):

For me, I had to also go to the Build Description add some text to the "Description" field and "What to Test" field.

Comment: This was also my problem, as far as I could tell. UI on that crap is probably the worst I've seen from apple. And that's saying A LOT.

Comment: Thank god! You almost saved a day.

Comment: For me, iTunes Connect would automatically ask for the missing "Build Description" when setting up "external testing", but I was initially setting up "internal testing", and there it did not ask me and simply spat out the error...

Answer (score 10):

For me it simply required waiting for the "Processing" step to complete on Apple's side.

Comment: Confirmed, this is the second time you see “Processing”, it is listed in the table next to post-first-processing icon. Wait a bit, then it changes to “Inactive” and then you can click the button.

Answer (score 8):

after following a hint at the Apple developer forums, I was able to solve the issue on my side.
https://devforums.apple.com/thread/255047?tstart=0

It seems you have to use version numbers with max one dot: X.XX

Having multiple dots will result in the above error. So don't use X.XX.XX

Another thing you should check is that you have the beta test entitlements in your distribution profile. This essentially means you should create a new distribution profile, it will have the new entitlements automatically.

Comment: I've been submitting apps with semver (X.X.X) for a while and never had this problem, so I don't think this is a definitive cause. I suspect (at least in my case) that it has to do with bitcode settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, what it was for me is that I had like 1.09 and 1.08 in my build numbers. Used the exact same process and changed it to 2.0 and it worked. I guess they don't allow multiple numbers after the decimal anymore or something, very odd. Thanks to DrMembrane for providing that link

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me. I submitted several builds to App Store/Test Flight without issue. Then I submitted a build with bitcode turned off. It took much longer than usual to process the build (six hours, whereas it usually takes around ten minutes), and then it was marked as failed. I tried again and the same thing happened.

Submitting the app again with bitcode turned on worked.

It seems like bitcode isn't "optional", after all, as Apple would have us believe.