# TestFlight There was an error importing this build?

Tags: ios, testflight

I am getting this error last 2 days, when I tried to upload version to TestFlight

> There was an error importing this build.

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089131/ios-testflight-there-was-an-error-loading-your-builds) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333394/itunes-connect-error-importing-this-build)

nothing worked, all uploaded builds has same Error after waiting 30 min of processing.

I got this email:

> Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
>   "***". Your delivery was successful, but you may wish to correct the
>   following issues in your next delivery:
>
> Too many symbol files - These symbols have no corresponding slice in
>   any binary [002EA978-D24A-33F2-82BB-5B3D1116C96A.symbols,
>   097F2BE5-5666-38A9-96CE-01F1A162EBE6.symbols,
>   09E2A9DD-84A9-3093-9E37-B181ABDCDCBF.symbols,
>   10A7AD15-1039-3615-9C1D-341CE529B575.symbols,
>   263C5DB3-252D-3EC2-AF8B-DDE4BAE9B8F1.symbols,
>   4B3F208B-6B74-32FC-8183-24A0C2576090.symbols,
>   658236EA-147C-37B9-9656-D43BDA0C07D4.symbols,
>   65B21C45-0115-3EF2-AB14-0FE34E345D7B.symbols,
>   71044FE5-3371-3CE9-9E52-3EB4B2B78517.symbols,
>   80B339BB-B742-31E0-9FFC-68791FFC6448.symbols,
>   83A32A72-D0C4-347D-A0D7-E026DA7AE278.symbols,
>   85537E2A-1778-3713-B787-250A89EBC0DD.symbols,
>   C4BF487B-CD55-321C-8C5A-7E2EB2337411.symbols,
>   C68E72E6-19DF-31EF-AB86-A1D0B78C2BEE.symbols,
>   CF19FC0E-9B5B-3889-A8D5-199D6252CF14.symbols,
>   DA9B9E34-DC7F-3DBC-B78E-57AAA08310F3.symbols,
>   E49B5364-F21F-3854-BF33-2CDD4EE5FFF9.symbols,
>   E554B9A5-A426-3E69-8854-7C7594D1E07E.symbols,
>   E9FFC603-4600-33D7-88B1-720410BE6C10.symbols,
>   EFBA36C0-AE7A-346C-BDB0-3BC90FC182F3.symbols]
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

so I have followed to solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313049/too-many-symbol-files-warnning-when-submitting-app/36784761)

**this is the results:**

```
UUID: 10A7AD15-1039-3615-9C1D-341CE529B575 (armv7) Alamofire.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Alamofire
UUID: 8956D8B2-9AA8-30DA-9179-8324D42EBF4D (arm64) Alamofire.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Alamofire
UUID: E9FFC603-4600-33D7-88B1-720410BE6C10 (armv7) Bolts.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Bolts
UUID: 371DD54B-CA58-33D1-9DC5-C9A045C3828F (arm64) Bolts.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Bolts
UUID: 71044FE5-3371-3CE9-9E52-3EB4B2B78517 (armv7) FBSDKCoreKit.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FBSDKCoreKit
UUID: 812DD16F-22EA-34B8-84F2-032FB1340703 (arm64) FBSDKCoreKit.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FBSDKCoreKit
UUID: E49B5364-F21F-3854-BF33-2CDD4EE5FFF9 (armv7) FBSDKLoginKit.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FBSDKLoginKit
UUID: 2326C15E-8947-3F1E-AE3D-A579E69136A2 (arm64) FBSDKLoginKit.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FBSDKLoginKit
UUID: 097F2BE5-5666-38A9-96CE-01F1A162EBE6 (armv7) FBSDKShareKit.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FBSDKShareKit
UUID: E708E310-ED6F-3D70-BEDD-43EDECD05CA2 (arm64) FBSDKShareKit.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FBSDKShareKit
UUID: 263C5DB3-252D-3EC2-AF8B-DDE4BAE9B8F1 (armv7) FacebookCore.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FacebookCore
UUID: FB7B9E58-CD23-33A2-A990-04AFE8F8F154 (arm64) FacebookCore.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FacebookCore
UUID: EFBA36C0-AE7A-346C-BDB0-3BC90FC182F3 (armv7) FacebookLogin.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FacebookLogin
UUID: 22166448-2486-3725-AC59-9B1EC28E90DD (arm64) FacebookLogin.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FacebookLogin
UUID: CF19FC0E-9B5B-3889-A8D5-199D6252CF14 (armv7) FacebookShare.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FacebookShare
UUID: DE424CE3-66B3-3018-93C7-7CB5A9294932 (arm64) FacebookShare.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FacebookShare
UUID: C4BF487B-CD55-321C-8C5A-7E2EB2337411 (armv7) GTMOAuth2.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/GTMOAuth2
UUID: ACFA7964-D97E-3221-8FD2-B9883E0A5450 (arm64) GTMOAuth2.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/GTMOAuth2
UUID: C68E72E6-19DF-31EF-AB86-A1D0B78C2BEE (armv7) GTMSessionFetcher.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/GTMSessionFetcher
UUID: 5347ACC8-51B0-3832-B88B-D27F0E831B8F (arm64) GTMSessionFetcher.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/GTMSessionFetcher
UUID: 002EA978-D24A-33F2-82BB-5B3D1116C96A (armv7) GoogleAPIClientForREST.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/GoogleAPIClientForREST
UUID: C80D22F5-FCFA-351C-A98E-62304DA35502 (arm64) GoogleAPIClientForREST.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/GoogleAPIClientForREST
UUID: E554B9A5-A426-3E69-8854-7C7594D1E07E (armv7) GoogleToolboxForMac.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/GoogleToolboxForMac
UUID: 4CFF534F-9CCA-37D3-A90C-C7AEB854164E (arm64) GoogleToolboxForMac.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/GoogleToolboxForMac
UUID: 83A32A72-D0C4-347D-A0D7-E026DA7AE278 (armv7) Kingfisher.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Kingfisher
UUID: B92CD3F3-7DC1-30A7-AFC4-E9EFB4AD4D04 (arm64) Kingfisher.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Kingfisher
UUID: 658236EA-147C-37B9-9656-D43BDA0C07D4 (armv7) Lottie.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Lottie
UUID: AC3CD0C0-B218-3CFB-B9A3-502FF5A907EC (arm64) Lottie.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Lottie
UUID: 378C2B8D-00F6-342B-8EB0-900BF6339C4E (arm64) Play and Win.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Play and Win
UUID: 09E2A9DD-84A9-3093-9E37-B181ABDCDCBF (armv7) Protobuf.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Protobuf
UUID: CC381BBE-52F9-342B-BB1B-10519200C82B (arm64) Protobuf.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/Protobuf
UUID: 4B3F208B-6B74-32FC-8183-24A0C2576090 (armv7) SDWebImage.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SDWebImage
UUID: E3A0196C-6CB6-3083-B355-0886168FB8F2 (arm64) SDWebImage.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SDWebImage
UUID: DA9B9E34-DC7F-3DBC-B78E-57AAA08310F3 (armv7) SwiftKeychainWrapper.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SwiftKeychainWrapper
UUID: 57A6EE05-5472-3A83-9C94-5D9EAC00891F (arm64) SwiftKeychainWrapper.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/SwiftKeychainWrapper
UUID: 85537E2A-1778-3713-B787-250A89EBC0DD (armv7) THLabel.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/THLabel
UUID: 46A4B180-8F99-3D20-BE43-68358B2C1C8C (arm64) THLabel.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/THLabel
UUID: 65B21C45-0115-3EF2-AB14-0FE34E345D7B (armv7) nanopb.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/nanopb
UUID: EDE18756-9C1A-33B8-B5BC-B9261CD78BE5 (arm64) nanopb.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/nanopb
```

[image]
how to solve this?

Comment: FYI - This is not an error, it is a warning.

Comment: @Nitish then why the build is not submited ? i have updated the question with more information

Comment: Uncheck the option - **Include symbols for your application to send crash reports**. I agree that if you want to send bug reports, this would probably not your best fit, but I guess this would fix the issue.

Comment: @Nitish already did that , same issue and same problem

Comment: Check if this is useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755240/too-many-symbol-files-after-successfully-submitting-my-apps

Comment: SAME ISSUE :/ i couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 1):

The solution

in my case it was `Firebase invites` pod , i removed it and its worked

Answer (score 0):

Best & Simple solution,

**Whenever you got warning of**

> Too many symbol files

Update your podfile as below,

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'DemoApp' do
  # Pods for DemoApp
  pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField'


  post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
              config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
              config.build_settings['DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT'] = 'dwarf'
              config.build_settings['LD_NO_PIE'] = 'NO'
          end

          if target.name == 'FlagPhoneNumber'
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                  config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.2'
              end
          end
      end
  end
end
```